# PyCharm / IntelliJ deletes empty folders by default

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

Is there a way to prevent PyCharm / IntelliJ from removing empty folders?

I write output files to a folder in my project. When I delete them, the default behaviour of PyCharm is to remove the empty folder.

Can I prevent this?

Comment: Are you using **git VCS** in this project?

Comment: Yes I am. Is that causing it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you delete the last file in a directory from Git in the command line (`git rm dir/file.txt`), Git itself automatically deletes the whole directory.

In other words: **IDE behaves the same as Git does.**

> Can I prevent this?

Nope. At least not at the moment.

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-75590 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified for any progress.

Comment: Thanks... I'll just place an empty file in there to prevent it for now.

Comment: An empty .gitignore file is one trick I've used before. `touch dir/.gitignore` and it's almost like an empty directory... :)

Comment: 1++ for empty hidden file :)